# Is there a YouTube <iframe> embed for the latest video on a channel?

Tags: video, embed

(Not sure if this is the right spot, feel free to direct me to the right area if it isn't.)

I'm needing to embed the latest video for the website that I'm working on's YouTube channel, and I'd prefer to be able to do it using the new iframe embed YouTube added a while ago.

Thing is, I'm not sure how to do it, since I can't find anything on YouTube's website. I don't need that channel embed thing, just the latest video on the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than that 'embed thing' you can count with Youtube API (http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api).

In other words, you can write code to process what is being pulled to feeds.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might have to be done via the API, but I wasn't really wanting to go down that route if possible (since it means loading the entire Zend framework to do it via PHP).

Comment: hmm... it doesn't really mean to load entire Zend framework to do it. I recently made a simple 'lastest videos' gallery on my client's site. He uploads on youtube, the website display them directly. No frameworks were used to do this simple task.

Comment: Found a SimpleXML example that got the YouTube embed. Heck of a lot easier to implement, that's for sure. :)